# angular js $location.path callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am using location.path(url) to navigate to a page, but I need to know if this has successfully completed before executing rest of the code. is there any callback function for this location service that I can utilize to place my code that must be executed after the location.path has been completed?

```
    $location.path("myurl");
    //code to be executed after the url navigation is completed successfully
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `$routeChangeSuccess` event defined in $route http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.$route service . You can subscribe to it using `$scope.on` method

Comment: watching $routeChangeSuccess will trigger for any route change. I need  to capture the specific route change related to "myUrl". Since location.path returns a string and has no callbacks, how can this be achieved?

Comment: The route arguments have information about current and previous routes which you can use for filter.